# How can I list unique characters used in a text file using linux command line tools?

Tags: linux, terminal, character, unique

I would like to list a set of characters used in a text file using linux command line tools. How can I achieve this ?

`uniq` utility works only on lines.

Comment: It seems to be a task for awk: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){chars[$(i)]=$(i);}} END{for(c in chars){print c;} }'` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $(i);};' file.txt | sort | uniq`

Comment: This worked :) can you post it as an answer and explain it ?

Answer (score 13):

I'd use `od`

```
od -cvAnone -w1
```

This lists characters, showing `\escapes` for non-displayables. Other [formats are available](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)

---

#### Examples:

So, to list the uniques:

```
od -cvAnone -w1 | sort -bu
```

Or to produce a top-20 histogram:

```
od -cvAnone -w1 | sort -b | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 20
```

See it **[Live On IdeOne](http://ideone.com/OAMWkF)**

Comment: I modified this slightly to use `| sort -u` at the end so I could see one representative of all the characters in a single file

Comment: @delliottg That's comment strikes me as funny, because ` | sort -bu` was already shown in my answer :)

Comment: Hah, totally missed that, not sure how, I was just excited to get `od -cvAnone -w1` working in my CYGWIN instance, then I sorted it uniquely (which ended being exactly what I needed), then came back here to upvote & comment, all w/o reading the rest of your post (till now).

Comment: unexpected output from `od -cvAnone -w1 <<< défaillir`

Answer (score 8):

I prefer this way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){chars[$(i)]=$(i);}} END{for(c in chars){print c;} }'
```

So this script is awk setipt. awk is useful for processing output of all sorts of commands.

This script have three parts:

- BEGIN, which is done once before procesing
- END, which is done after processing
- in the middle there is a loop that handles the output

1)

```
BEGIN{FS=""}
```

From here http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html#Field-Splitting-Summary

> FS == ""
>       Each individual character in the record becomes a separate field. (This is a gawk extension; it is not specified by the POSIX standard.)

2)

```
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){chars[$(i)]=$(i);}}
```

`chars` is just an one-dimensional associative array (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Basics.html#Array-Basics). I add values in it while processing each char.

3)

```
END{for(c in chars){print c;} }
```

The final section - walk through the whole array `chars` and just print its indexes . http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html#Scanning-an-Array

PS.

As for @sehe way of processing.
Look for a relatively big text file. It is >six times faster to use an associative array:

```
>time od -cvAnone -w1 vector.html.big | sort -bu > /dev/null

real    0m1.597s
user    0m1.619s
sys     0m0.022s

>time awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){chars[$(i)]=$(i);}} END{for(c in chars){print c;} }' vector.html.big | sort >/dev/null

real    0m0.252s
user    0m0.251s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: on the timings: it matters a bit what the input is; the awk appears to  be ~4 to 6x faster (for [full binary data](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12305496/) vs. [a..z only](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12305484/))

Comment: interestingly, much of the difference goes away when using C locale: [full binary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12305534/) both [a..z only](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12305544/), both only ~2x the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl way, which prints the Unicode code point and the character itself :

```bash
perl -C7 -ne 'for (split(//)) {print sprintf("U+%04X", ord)." ".$_."\n"}' $Your_File | sort -u
```

Or on multiple lines for readability:

```bash
perl -C7 -ne 'for ( split(//) ) {
    print sprintf("U+%04X", ord) . " " . $_ . "\n"
    }' $Your_File \
| sort -u
```